# global inline function between two c files

Tags: c, global, inline-functions

Following from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592028/force-another-file-to-define-a-function/28592102#28592102) I asked before. I want to know how could I define an `inline` function in global scope.

I want to **declare** `inline` function in test.h, **define** it in main.c and **call** it from test.c.

main.c and test.c both `#include "test.h"` (for code sample please click the link above).

This is basiclly some sort of callback function that user can enable/disable. And only one file should have the function **defined**.

I know `inline` is just a suggestion to the compiler and it doesnt make much difference on modern CPUs but this is for 8-bit microcontroller and would really need it.

**EDIT:**

I have a function in test.c which calls this inlined function. I just want to replace the call with the body of function defined in main.c. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's mandatory that there exists only one defintion.

Comment: @lurker Wouldnt that require me to include `main.c` ? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: It's the linker who takes care of that, the definition shall exist only once, you then tell the compiler what is the function prototype in another c file, and in the linking stage the linker finds the definition of the funcion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way it works is exactly like that, you will have only one definition of the function, say it's the function `int add(int x, int y);` then you define it in `main.c`

**main.c**:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

then if you want to use it in another c file all you need is this

**test.c**

```
int add(int x, int y); /* just a declaration, a function prototype */

int addWrapper(int x, int y)
{
    return add(x, y);
}
```

compile it like this

```
gcc -Wall -Werror main.c test.c -o some_output_file_name
```

and the linker will take care of finding the function definition.

If the function is not defined in any of the compiled files, then a

```
Undefined reference to `int add(int x, int y);' in ...
```

error will be issued.

If you want to force the compiler to insert the function body, then insert the function body yourself, use a preprocessor macro

**header.h**

```c
#define add(x,y) ((x) + (y))
```

and then

```c
#include "header.h"

int addWrapper(int x, int y)
{
    return add(x, y);
}
```

will replace `add(x, y)` with `x + y`.

If the function returns `void` then a nice trick is to use this

```c
#define inlinedFunction(parameters) \
    do {                            \
        /* function body here */    \
    } while (0)
```

you should add a continuation backslash at the end of every line in the macro definition.

Comment: But that doesn't *inline* the function as the OP is requesting, does it? That's just a standard function call.

Comment: Using macros could work, but is just ugly. You're sure there isnt another way? I really need the user (main.c) to define that function, not somehere in a header.

Comment: @user1806687 If you want to ensure that the code will be replaced there isn't and why is it ugly? you will have it in your header file and call it as if it was a function.

Comment: Because the user will have to make a `#define` statement instead of just making a function.

Comment: @user1806687 I don't understand, why would the user need a define? you provide it within your header file.

Comment: Inline functions and macros are completely different things. You define inline functions with "inline" keyword. Inline functions are parsed by compiler but macros are parsed by preprocessor and inline functions are typesafe but not macros. So this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Most 8-bit microcontroller code is written in language that approximates C89 (there are often extensions, e.g. inline assembly), and `inline` was not *officially* part of C until C99.  So first of all identify what standard you are compiling for (if any) and consult your compiler manual if `inline` is an extension (i.e. not C99 inline).  Compiler manuals take precedence over C standards in that realm of programming.

Per `C99` If both `main.c` and `test.c` both need to call the same function AND it needs to be marked `inline`, then I believe it MUST be defined in the header because an `inline` function cannot span translation units (i.e. ".c" files).

For example:

**test.h:**

```
static inline int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

**main.c:**

```
#include "test.h"
void main(void)
{
   int x = add(10,15);
}
```

**test.c:**

```
#include "test.h"
int test(void)
{
   int x = add(10,15);
   return x;
}
```

**EDIT:** See here for better explanation of C99 `inline` usage: [How to declare an inline function in C99 multi-file project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229343/)

However, this can cause all sorts of weird behavior with the resulting object code.  For example, I've seen a compiler from a *major* MCU mfg (who will intentionally go unnamed) generate object code for `inline` functions `#included` in a given translation unit **instead of inlining them**.  The file was included in several places and contained many functions so this caused a massive increase in overall ROM usage throughout the code base because the linker was also incapable of removing dead code (see `--gc-sections` for `gcc`) AND failed to improve performance because the functions were never actually inlined, even though it was *technically* the correct use of inline.

Our solution to this particular problem was to convert all the functions to macros (which gave the perfomance benefit intended with `inline`) but an alternate approach would have been removing the `inline` from the declaration and moving the definiton to a single `.c` file.

**TL;DR:** If using `inline` for MCUs, 1) consult your compiler manual, and 2) keep an eye on object code generated.

Comment: @user1806687  I stand corrected (slightly) on the C99 `inline` usage.  See updated answer & link for more info.  Cautions about watching the generated code still stands though.

Comment: `static inline` should make sure that no symbol and code is generated for a function.

Comment: @nwellnhof - it didn't for the compiler in question.  But for GCC, he should be fine.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland So how would I use `static inline` in code to achieve this?

Comment: See updated example.  I believe it will do what you're after if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland I mean how would I use this. Should I use `staic inline void some_func(void);` in test.h, and `static inline void some_func(void) {}` in main.c. But this gives errors.

Comment: No, remove the `static inline void some_funct(void){}` from main.c.  Inline functions technically cannot exist across multiple translation units.  Putting it in the header is effectively doing a copy/paste into every `.c` that includes the header, but you still only *maintain* one version of the code.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland Ahh, it makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean what you say, that the function in question is a callback, you can't inline a callback. It doesn't make sense, the callback-call usually happens through a function pointer, I don't think you can expect the compiler to prove that its value is constant (and known at compile-time) so that it can replace the call with inlined code.

Comment: I have a function in test.c which calls this `inlined` function. I just want to replace the call with the body of function defined in main.c. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @user1806687 use a macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inline` keyword in C but if you're using GNU GCC compiler it will require inline functions to be `static` functions also. So you will be only available to use these functions on the same source file. If you want to declare a global inline function that you define in some header file and use it on source files that includes that header file you can use GNU GCC's `always_inline` attribute as following:

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int foo(int a)
{
  return a+2;
}
```

Don't forget to declare body of the inline function in the same header file.